# "Distribute to" vs. "distribute among"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> Sumit distributed the sweets **__** his friends.

In the above sentence, I couldn't tell whether to use *to* or *among*. The answer given is *among*. Why not *to*?

Answer (score 3):

*Distributed* suggests that he shared out the sweets in such a way that, in the absence of any other indication, all his friends received more or less a fair share. That sense requires *distributed* to be followed by *among*.

*To his friends* would normally follow *gave* rather than *distributed*, and it would mean that his friends received the sweets, but would not necessarily say anything about the proportion each of them received.